# Coding Multiple RadioGroups

Tags: java, android, xml, eclipse

I'm creating a basic app in Android Studio:

There are 3 categories with a radio group for each category.

The user selects one button from each category then hits "Choose".

A Textview should show a message, e.g. "You chose Chinese, Level 1, Guess the City".

I've worked out how to say "You chose Chinese" but can't figure out how to add the rest using `if` conditions. Any ideas?

```
<TextView android:id="@+id/text" />
<RadioGroup android:id="@+id/radio1">
    <RadioButton id="@+id/chinese"
        android:text="@string/chinese" />
    <RadioButton android:id="@+id/indian"
        android:text="@string/indian" />
    <RadioButton android:id="@+id/russian"
        android:text="@string/russian" />
</RadioGroup>
<RadioGroup android:id="@+id/radio2">
    <RadioButton android:id="@+id/difficulty1"
        android:text="@string/starter" />
    <RadioButton android:id="@+id/difficulty2"
            android:text="@string/medium" />
    <RadioButton android:id="@+id/difficulty3"
            android:text="@string/expert" />
</RadioGroup>
<RadioGroup android:id="@+id/radio3">
    <RadioButton android:id="@+id/challenge1"
            android:text="@string/buildingbricks" />
    <RadioButton android:id="@+id/challenge2"
            android:text="@string/callcentre" />
    <RadioButton android:id="@+id/challenge3"
            android:text="@string/city" />
</RadioGroup>
```

---

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private RadioGroup radioGroup1
    private RadioButton chinese, indian, russian;
    private Button button;
    private TextView textView;

    public String string_first_radiogroup, 

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        radioGroup1 = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radio1);


        radioGroup1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
                if(checkedId == R.id.chinese) {
                    string_first_radiogroup="Chinese";
                } else if(checkedId == R.id.indian) {
                    string_first_radiogroup="Indian"; 
                } else {
                    string_first_radiogroup="Russian";
                }
            }
        });

        chinese = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.chinese);
        indian = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.indian);
        russian = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.russian);
        textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);


        button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.choose);
        button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                textView.setText("You chose " + string_first_radiogroup + " option");
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try below code:

```
button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                textView.setText("You chose " + ((RadioButton)findViewById(radioGroup1.getCheckedRadioButtonId())).getText() + " option");
            }
        });
```

Comment: Thanks Pratik! I've added the code. How would I now add the "if" statements for the second and third radio group?